# Ajuda Update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade

Boa noite, estou começando a estudar Laravel e me deparei com um problema que já me tomou algumas horas em busca de uma solução. Preciso fazer um update em um formulário, e quando dou o submit recebo o erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Segue os meus códigos:
Rota:

```
Route::get('/produtos/edita/{id}', 'ProdutoController@edita')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::post('/produtos/atualiza', 'ProdutoController@atualiza');
```

Blade:

```
@extends('layout.principal')
@section('conteudo')

<h1>Editar Produto: {{$p->nome}}</h1>

<form action="/produtos/atualiza" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$p->id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input name="nome" class="form-control" value="{{$p->nome}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Descrição</label>
    <input name="descricao" class="form-control" value="{{$p->descricao}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Valor</label>
    <input name="valor" class="form-control" value="{{$p->valor}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Quantidade</label>
    <input type="number" name="quantidade" class="form-control" value="{{$p->quantidade}}">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Adicionar</button>
</form>
@stop
```

---

Controller:

```
 public function edita($id)
{
$produto = Produto::find($id);
return view('produto.editar')->with('p', $produto);
}

public function atualiza()
{
$params = Request::all(); 
$produto = Produto::find($params->id);
$produto->fill($params->except('id'));
$produto->save();
return redirect()->action('ProdutoController@lista');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa passar o `id` no `verb` `post`, você só precisa criar um `input` `hidden` e guardar o valor `id` nesse campo, mas, se ainda quiser do jeito que fez precisa passar na tag `form` o `id` porque o endereço realmente vai dar `404` *(porque o endereço colocado não existe, ele precisa do código no final, igual está estipulado em sua rota*), ***mude***

```
<form action="/produtos/atualiza" method="post">
```

***para***

```
<form action="/produtos/atualiza/{$p->id}" method="post">
```

esse mudança é mediante a sua rota, mas, se eu fosse você faria corretamente assim:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/produtos/edita/{id}', 'ProdutoController@edita')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::post('/produtos/atualiza', 'ProdutoController@atualiza');
```

**Html:**

```
@extends('layout.principal')
@section('conteudo')
    <h1>Editar Produto: {{$p->nome}}</h1>
    <form action="/produtos/atualiza" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$p->id}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nome</label>
        <input name="nome" class="form-control" value="{{$p->nome}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Descrição</label>
        <input name="descricao" class="form-control" value="{{$p->descricao}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Valor</label>
        <input name="valor" class="form-control" value="{{$p->valor}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quantidade</label>
        <input type="number" name="quantidade" 
               class="form-control" value="{{$p->quantidade}}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
@stop
```

**Controller:**

```
public function edita($id)
{
    $produto = Produto::find($id);
    return view('produto.editar')->with('p', $produto);
}

public function atualiza()
{
    $params = Request::all(); 
    $produto = Produto::find($params['id']);
    $produto->fill($params);
    $produto->save();
    return redirect()->action('ProdutoController@lista');
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests)
- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)
- [Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers)

Comment: Fazendo da segunda maneira que apresentou, recebo o erro "Too few arguments to function estoque\Http\Controllers\ProdutoController::atualiza(). 0 passed and exactly 1 expected". Pelo que entendi ele não esta conseguindo receber o id do form

Comment: @João peço desculpas, faltou remover o `$id` do parâmetro agora deve funcionar

Comment: eu ja havia testado retirando ele, ai recebo o erro na linha Produto::find, onde o erro é : "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object". Já estou a alguns dias tentando solucionar isso, ate consegui fazendo umas gambiarras ou de maneiras que acredito não serem as ideias, mais gostaria de deixar de uma maneira o mais próximo da ideal possível.

Comment: @João você mudou o form para está enviando o valor corretamente, em qual método é o erro agora? explica bem o problema!

Comment: atualizei a postagem com uma foto do erro, e atualizei meus codigos para a maneira atual seguindo suas recomendações. Veja se consegue entender, qualquer coisa so avisar

Comment: Preste atenção no meu atualiza e no seu atualiza tem diferença ! @João

Comment: Tinha me esquecido de atualizar a parte de controller aqui no post, agora esta idêntico, na verdade cheguei a dar crt + c e crt + v no seu código no meu. Se não for lhe tomar muito mais tempo, posso subir meu projeto inteiro para você olhar.